# Strange misbehaviour with chaining PHP Wordpress Post Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, chain

I am trying to simply output all posts but everything is working fine but I want to add the classes in the  tag but the classes gets written in plain text not into the tag.

my code:

```
<?php
            if (have_posts()) :
                // Start the Loop.
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                    echo '<article id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '" ' . post_class() . '>';
                    twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail();
                    the_title('<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>');
                    echo '<div class="entry-summary">';
                    the_excerpt();
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</article>';


                endwhile;

            endif;
            ?>
```

I think it has something to do with the chaining but I tried everything... :(

[image: placed outside of tag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
echo '<article id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '" ' . post_class() . '>';
```

with

```
echo '<article id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '" ';
post_class();
echo '>';
```

Comment: @BillBronson - the `post_class()` function directly outputs the code and in effect gets run _before_ your `echo` command which invokes it. Separating them like I did in my code above takes care of that issue.